# Show last date modified in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to show the last modified date for each file and folder in the specifically in the Explorer window of VS Code? If it's not possible by changing the settings, are there any extensions that do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I use the VS Code [filesize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkxml.vscode-filesize) extension. It shows the size of the file in the bottom status bar. If you click on this size figure you will immediately see a table with the date of file creation and the date of the file update like the following:[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to jump in with a [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brunnerh.file-properties-viewer) to the best solution I found so far (and a link to the [original repository](https://github.com/brunnerh/file-properties-viewer), in case the link to marketplace changes).

But the ultimate solution (I think) would be to show that info in the status bar - I will hopefully remember to update this answer if I ever come across such a solution!

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a whole array of extensions available nowadays, for such matter:

[image: vscode_extensions_available_11/2022]